# How to extract data from an embedded fusion table map

Tags: kml, google-fusion-tables

Hi I would like to view this map in Google Earth, how can I export a KML file.
The Google Fusion Table has a public embedded map but this cannot be viewed with current position navigation etc.
It seems as if Fusion tables are not a current thing any more?
If I could access the raw data that would also be OK.

Any help reverse engineering this will be greatly appreciated.

https://fusiontables.googleusercontent.com/embedviz?q=select+col14+from+1IjOEsYoND06MJ5rm-tWHPF_zovBoIojnTf5nhBtY&viz=MAP&h=false&lat=-43.51203571037226&lng=172.69052770785004&t=1&z=14&l=col14&y=2&tmplt=2&hml=TWO_COL_LAT_LNG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open [this link](https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?docid=1IjOEsYoND06MJ5rm-tWHPF_zovBoIojnTf5nhBtY), switch to the Map tab, select File > Download in the menu and you'll see the KML options activated. This doesn't work when you're in the other tabs. You have to be within the Map tab.

Comment: Thanks so much that's exactly what I was looking for. Presumably you managed to edit the link to give the table view?

Comment: I took the docid (1IjOEsYoND06MJ5rm-tWHPF_zovBoIojnTf5nhBtY) from your link and append it to the datasource link.